# Using bash function + grc like an alias breaks Zsh completion

Tags: bash, zsh, oh-my-zsh, ansi-escape, zsh-completion

I'm using grc / grcat to colorize my terminal output with this function:

```
function docker() {
  case $* in
    ps* ) shift 1; command docker ps "$@" | grcat $HOME/.grc/conf.dockerps ;;
    images* ) shift 1; command docker images "$@" | grcat $HOME/.grc/conf.dockerimages ;;
    info* ) shift 1; command docker info "$@" | grcat $HOME/.grc/conf.dockerinfo ;;
    * ) command docker "$@" ;;
  esac
}
```

but this is breaking the my zsh completions and plugins that I setup using oh-my-zsh in my .zshrc with this:

```
plugins=(git colored-man-pages colorize vagrant brew ruby docker)
plugins+=(gradle rvm rails bundler gem osx pod)
plugins+=(bower cp go node npm)
plugins+=(zsh-syntax-highlighting encode64)
plugins+=(zsh-completions mvn)

fpath=(~/.zsh/completion $fpath)

autoload -Uz compinit && compinit -i
```

When I try using `docker stop` for example, the completion is coming with ANSI escape sequences: `$'\033'\[0m$'\033'\[1m$'\033'\[33mhigh_wright$'\033'\[0m`

is there a way to avoid that and filter those escape sequences only for completions?

**EDIT**

I found this file in my .oh-my-zsh dir for the docker plugin: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/docker/_docker

I understand that I need to change this function but I don't know how.

```
__docker_containers() {
    declare -a cont_cmd
    cont_cmd=($(docker ps | awk 'NR>1{print $NF":[CON("$1")"$2"("$3")]"}'))
    if [[  'X$cont_cmd' != 'X' ]]
        _describe 'containers' cont_cmd
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing the docker plugin from oh-my-zsh that is installed in `.oh-my-zsh/plugins/docker/_docker`. To fix it I preceded all helper functions with `command` like this:

```
__docker_containers() {
    declare -a cont_cmd
    cont_cmd=($(command docker ps | awk 'NR>1{print $NF":[CON("$1")"$2"("$3")]"}'))
    if [[  'X$cont_cmd' != 'X' ]]
        _describe 'containers' cont_cmd
}
```